# Filter results using php or javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, smarty

I'm new to developing in PHP, Smarty using MySQL. I would like an expert opinion on the following, or any good advise will do.

So I made an *index.php* which connects to database(MySQL) also Smarty, reads my data through query and displays them from my *index.tpl* file. Same for my products, *product.php* connects to database, does a query, and displays my products on the *product.tpl* page.

For my *index.php* I would like to add a filter displaying product by price from high-to-low or from low-to-high.

**What do you suggest:**

Do you suggest I use Javascript for the filter or just query it from database for when ever that select value is selected?

Or how would be the best valid way of doing this? Any tips on this will do thanks in advance.

My database for now have only like 3 products, I'm just testing.

**.php**

```
<?php

$new = ['product_id','product_category','product_price','product_quantity','product_about','product_color'];

//Database connection
$db = mysqli_connect('xxx','xxx','xxx','xxx') or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');

//access Smarty template engine
require_once('Smarty-3.1.30/libs/Smarty.class.php');

$smarty = new Smarty();
$smarty->template_dir = 'views';
$smarty->compile_dir = 'tmp';


//query product page
$query = "SELECT * FROM cs_shop";

if ($productPrice > 0) {
    $query .= " WHERE `product_price` = ".$productPrice;
}


mysqli_query($db, $query) or die('Error querying database.');

$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);

if ( !empty($_GET['sort']) && $_GET['sort'] == 'PriceAsc' ) {
    $result =" ORDER BY `product_price` ASC";
} 
if ( !empty($_GET['sort']) && $_GET['sort'] == 'PriceDesc' ) {
    $result =" ORDER BY `product_price` DESC";
}




//query an array of products
$rows = array();

 //loop start
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $rows[] = array(
        'product_id' => $row['product_id'],
        'product_category' => $row['product_category'],
        'product_price' => $row['product_price'],
        'product_quantity' => $row['product_quantity'],
        'product_about' => $row['product_about'],
        'product_color' => $row['product_color']
    );
}

//db collect data
$smarty->assign('row', $rows); 
//template
$smarty->display('index.tpl');

mysqli_close($db);

?>
```

**.tpl** (this is loop for displaying product-listing)

```
    <form method="get" name="sort">
    <select name="sort" id="sort">
                <option value=''>--Select--</option>
                <option value='PriceAsc'>high to low</option>
                <option value='PriceDesc'>low to high</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Sort"/>
    </form>



<div class="test divider">
            {section name=prod loop=$row}
                <div class="colm3">
                    <div class="col3 r1">
                        <div class="products-container">
                            <h5>{$row[prod].product_name}</h5>
                            <a class="producy_img_link" href="#" >
                                <img src="{$row[prod].prod_img}" style="width:auto; height:255px;">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <a href="#">
                        <div class="block-right">
                            <h6>{$row[prod].product_vintage}</h6>
                            <h5>{$row[prod].product_veriatel}</h5>
                            <div>
                                <span class="price">R {$row[prod].product_price}</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                {/section}
</div>
```

Now whenever I click on high to low I want the products to filter by price from high to low, I think there would be an easy way using a query but I'm stuck with this.

Comment: you can do in php for each(filter up /down) event a query usnig order by price DESC/ASC

Comment: In think that using the db  with proper query .. eg building a php function for search on db is the better way

Comment: the best solution would be to use `AJAX` or use this [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) jQuery library

Comment: If you got a lot of data (which i assume) it should be faster (and more effective) to send a `AJAX` request to php which queries the database and sorts for you. Sorting via JavaScript is also possible, but remember that JavaScript runs at the client-pc, so if it is very slow the sorting also will take it's time (or even take up too much ram). Also you would have to send all of the data to the client and let mysql handle it.

Comment: Exactly the answer i was waiting on  Thanks @TobiasF.  , so function using AJAX in php would be the best way to go since JQuery would be very slow especially if i have allot of products, thanks for the great answer, explains allot in few words! thanks for other tips aswell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `AJAX` to sort the table, give your table headers `name` attribute and on click of the header table get the name attribute of the table header and make `AJAX` call to your `PHP`.

```js
$('th').on('click', function () {
    var name = $(this).attr('name');

    console.log('AJAX will sort by: ' + name);
    // this is the AJAX call
    // $.post('somephpgage.php', {sortby: name}, function (response) {
    // $('#table-result').html(response);
    // });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="table-result">
    <table style="width:100%">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th name="firstname">Firstname</th>
            <th name="lastname">Lastname</th>
            <th name="age">Age</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Jill</td>
            <td>Smith</td>
            <td>50</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Eve</td>
            <td>Jackson</td>
            <td>94</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Then in your `PHP`

```
<?php

    $new = ['product_id', 'product_category', 'product_price', 'product_quantity', 'product_about', 'product_color'];

    //Database connection
    $db = mysqli_connect('xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx')
    or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');

    //access Smarty template engine
    require_once('Smarty-3.1.30/libs/Smarty.class.php');

    $smarty = new Smarty();
    $smarty->template_dir = 'views';
    $smarty->compile_dir = 'tmp';
    //query product page
    $query = "SELECT * FROM cs_shop";


    if (!empty($_GET['sort']) && $_GET['sort'] == 'PriceAsc') {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM cs_shop ORDER BY price ASC";
    } elseif (!empty($_GET['sort']) && $_GET['sort'] == 'PriceDesc') {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM cs_shop ORDER BY price DESC";
    }

    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);

    //query an array of products
    $rows = array();

    //loop start
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $rows[] = array(
            'product_id' => $row['product_id'],
            'product_category' => $row['product_category'],
            'product_price' => $row['product_price'],
            'product_quantity' => $row['product_quantity'],
            'product_about' => $row['product_about'],
            'product_color' => $row['product_color']
        );
    }

    //db collect data
    $smarty->assign('row', $rows);
    //template
    $smarty->display('index.tpl');

    mysqli_close($db);

    ?>
```

**Using AJAX** add an `id="sort-ajax"` to this div `<div class="test divider">`

```
<select name="sort" id="sort">
    <option value=''>--Select--</option>
    <option value='PriceAsc'>high to low</option>
    <option value='PriceDesc'>low to high</option>
</select>

<!-- add this at the bottom of your page, just before </body> -->
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('#sort').on('change', function () {
        $.post('sort.php', {sort: $(this).val()}, function (response) {
            $('#sort-ajax').html(response);
        });
    })
</script>
```

Create a new `PHP` file called `sort.php`, we are going to send our `AJAX` call to this page.

```
<?php
//Database connection
$db = mysqli_connect('xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx')
or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');

$query = "SELECT * FROM cs_shop";


if (!empty($_POST['sort']) && $_POST['sort'] == 'PriceAsc') {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM cs_shop ORDER BY price ASC";
} elseif (!empty($_POST['sort']) && $_POST['sort'] == 'PriceDesc') {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM cs_shop ORDER BY price DESC";
}

$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);


//loop start
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) : ?>
    <div class="colm3">
        <div class="col3 r1">
            <div class="products-container">
                <h5><?= $row['product_name']; ?></h5>
                <a class="producy_img_link" href="#">
                    <img src="{$row[prod].prod_img}" style="width:auto; height:255px;">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <a href="#">
            <div class="block-right">
                <h6><?= $row['product_vintage']; ?></h6>
                <h5><?= $row['product_veriatel']; ?></h5>
                <div>
                    <span class="price">R <?= $row['product_price']; ?></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>

<?php endwhile;
mysqli_close($db);
```

Comment: Wow, thanks im trying this @julekgwa for this example ill give this a go! thanks! wil come back if it works

Comment: I commented out the `AJAX` here as `PHP` doesn't run on SO, remove the comments on your side.

Comment: oh haha was so confused with that, cool as i did , thanks, getting there!

Comment: im also from SA capetown ,btw! @julekgwa

Comment: quick question , was reading up about json, js, php, AJAX, i just want to know is it better loading with js wich is client side? or is it better using AJAX which is server side , it confuses me i cant think making a db connection for a query each time is good, but then using json would solve this, but for now im using just php, js, AJAX and Smarty..

Comment: $sortby = $_POST['sortby'];   --> this gives me 'Error querying database' ... @2by2

Comment: im going to show you my script and then if you would like you can help me, i think using ur method im missing allot of code so i tried something new.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144638/discussion-between-2by2-and-ylama).